# NVL function doesn't work properly

Tags: sql, database, plsql

I am supposed to do the script which should calculate the average charge per month.
In the below screen shot you can see the average values which I should receive.

```
OP_Yearly           
         counter charge minutes
Oct 2012    1   5.16    1.32
Nov 2012    1   54.44   14.42
Dec 2012    0   0.00    0.00

    Average:    19.86464    5.246666667
```

However, the problem is that I receive this average value, where the charge is not divided by month which has zero values.

```
OP_Yearly           
         counter charge minutes
Oct 2012    1   5.16    1.32
Nov 2012    1   54.44   14.42
Dec 2012    0   0.00    0.00

    Average:    29.79696    7.87
```

This is my script -

```
   SELECT op,
       SUM (counter) AS counter,
       AVG (NVL (Charge_SDR, 0)) AS AVERAGE_CHARGE_SDR_YTD,
       AVG (NVL (Minutes, 0)) AS AVERAGE_MINUTES_YTD
  FROM (
  SELECT t.op AS op,
           COUNT (DISTINCT t.im) AS counter,
           (SUM (t.charge / POWER (10, t.decimals))) AS Charge_SDR,
           CAST (SUM (t.duration / 60) AS NUMBER (10, 2)) Minutes
      FROM top t, oper o
     WHERE t.op = o.op AND timestamp LIKE '201210%' AND o.TYPE = 'M'
GROUP BY t.op,
UNION ALL
  SELECT t.op AS op,
         COUNT (DISTINCT t.im) AS counter,
         (SUM (t.charge / POWER (10, t.decimals))) AS Charge_SDR,
         CAST (SUM (t.duration / 60) AS NUMBER (10, 2)) Minutes
    FROM top t, oper o
   WHERE t.op = o.op AND timestamp LIKE '201211%' AND o.TYPE = 'M'
GROUP BY t.op,
UNION ALL
  SELECT t.op AS op,
         COUNT (DISTINCT t.im) AS counter,
         (SUM (t.charge / POWER (10, t.decimals))) AS Charge_SDR,
         CAST (SUM (t.duration / 60) AS NUMBER (10, 2)) Minutes
    FROM top t, oper o
   WHERE t.op = o.op AND timestamp LIKE '201212%' AND o.TYPE = 'M'
GROUP BY t.op, )
GROUP BY op;
```

It is easy to make it divided by 3 months (sum(Charge_SDR) / 3), but I want to know how to do it with NVL function. I have included in script NVL, but it doesn't catch this month which has zero value. Any ideas how to correct it?
Thanks for helping me in advance

Comment: The images in your post aren't showing up so I can't see what the issue is.  You might want to use JPEG's instead of PNG's for your images as not all systems and browsers can display PNG's successfully.  Thanks.

Comment: Better yet, use plain text.

Comment: The problem is that the subquery for December isn't returning any rows, so the result of the union just has 2 rows, not 3.

Comment: Still can't see the images. As @Barmar suggested, it might be better to include your expected values as text instead of trying to link in an image.

Comment: Do you have a calendar table available that has a row for every date?  That would make it a lot easier to handle year-months without data.

Comment: I changed the images in JPEG's and hope that now you can see them. Yes, the problem is that the subquery for December isn't returning any rows. I have tried to use NVL in subquery, too. However, it doesn't working

Comment: No, I don't have such a calendar table

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery isn't returning a row for the months with zero records. Use an outer join with a list of months to create null rows for them.

```
SELECT op,
       SUM (counter) AS counter,
       AVG (NVL (Charge_SDR, 0)) AS AVERAGE_CHARGE_SDR_YTD,
       AVG (NVL (Minutes, 0)) AS AVERAGE_MINUTES_YTD
FROM (
  SELECT t.op AS op,
         SUBSTR(timestamp, 1, 6) AS month,
         COUNT (DISTINCT t.im) AS counter,
         (SUM (t.charge / POWER (10, t.decimals))) AS Charge_SDR,
         CAST (SUM (t.duration / 60) AS NUMBER (10, 2)) Minutes
    FROM top t, oper o
   WHERE t.op = o.op AND timestamp LIKE '201210%' AND o.TYPE = 'M'
GROUP BY t.op,
UNION ALL
  SELECT t.op AS op,
         SUBSTR(timestamp, 1, 6) AS month,
         COUNT (DISTINCT t.im) AS counter,
         (SUM (t.charge / POWER (10, t.decimals))) AS Charge_SDR,
         CAST (SUM (t.duration / 60) AS NUMBER (10, 2)) Minutes
    FROM top t, oper o
   WHERE t.op = o.op AND timestamp LIKE '201211%' AND o.TYPE = 'M'
GROUP BY t.op,
UNION ALL
  SELECT t.op AS op,
         SUBSTR(timestamp, 1, 6) AS month,
         COUNT (DISTINCT t.im) AS counter,
         (SUM (t.charge / POWER (10, t.decimals))) AS Charge_SDR,
         CAST (SUM (t.duration / 60) AS NUMBER (10, 2)) Minutes
    FROM top t, oper o
   WHERE t.op = o.op AND timestamp LIKE '201212%' AND o.TYPE = 'M') t
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT '201210' month
            FROM dual
            UNION SELECT '201211'
            FROM dual
            UNION SELECT '201212'
            FROM dual) m
ON t.month = m.month
GROUP BY op;
```

Comment: It give me this error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected. I tried to correct it, but I am not sure where to put FROM. FROM is missing in this part - RIGHT JOIN (SELECT '201210' month UNION SELECT '201211' UNION SELECT '201212')

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to MySQL, which doesn't require a table there. PLSQL uses DUAL, I've added it.

Comment: Thanks for help but again the charge is not divided by month which has zero value. I run the select for December and there isn't returning any record.

Comment: The other problem is that `op` is NULL for those months, so `GROUP BY op` filters them out.